# Firefox and IE9 different handling of scrollbars when overflow:auto

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, scrollbar, overflow

Hope you can help me. I am wanting my div with max-height and overflow:auto to render the scrollbars **inside the element**

```
div
{
    overflow:auto;
    max-height:700px;
}
```

Firefox and Chrome are, as desired, putting the vertical scrollbar inside the overflowing div, however IE9 is putting the scrollbar outside of the div.

Can anyone help me get that scrollbar inside the element on IE?

You can see the actual page here:
http://new.lambwatch.co.uk/chat.htm

And the scrolling div is that div on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

in head. If doesn't help, try to not float the div with scrollbar.

Comment: It was the float that did it. Thanks :)